# BeautifulSoup: something similar to .head() function in Pandas

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following BeautifulSoup object:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = 'https://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/content/viewform/adv/Sections/iapd_AdvPrivateFundReportingSection.aspx?ORG_PK=161227&FLNG_PK=05C43A1A0008018C026407B10062D49D056C8CC0'
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
```

What I'm looking for is something like the .head() function in Pandas. I want to see something at the top of the frame, but the object is too long for me to scroll to the top.

I've looked all over but I haven't found anything yet. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The first few lines of *what*?

Comment: It's a nice thought but unlike pandas this is not flat but hierarchical data. You can do something like `soup.prettify().splitlines()[:20]`

Comment: What kind of output are you looking for? You *could* simply truncate the html, but you don't need `BeautifulSoup` for that (and it wouldn't be valid html either).

Comment: What I'm looking for is the same output as you get if you type "soup" and enter after the code above, but just the top part displayed as opposed to the bottom.

Comment: Try `l = soup.prettify().splitlines(); print('\n'.join(l[:20] + ['...'] + 'l[-20:]))` Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem isn't specific to `BeautifulSoup`, it's a matter of truncating a string as @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ says:

```
numlines = 20
print('\n'.join(soup.prettify().splitlines()[:numlines]))
```

Adjust `numlines` as needed. You could also use `html.text` since we're not dealing with the structure of the document in any way.